# Loading configuration classes present in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I have a Spring MVC application with multiple separate modules which all have their own JavaConfig @Configuration class. My goal is to load all spring configurations that are present in the war. Depending on options passed to the build command some modules and thus configurations may not be present and so `@Import` isn't an option as it would throw `ClassDefNotFound`.

In the spring documentation it says

> @Configuration is meta-annotated with @Component, therefore @Configuration classes are candidates for component scanning (typically using Spring XML's  element) and therefore may also take advantage of @Autowired/@Inject at the field and method level (but not at the constructor level).
>
> @Configuration classes may not only be bootstrapped using component scanning, but may also themselves configure component scanning using the @ComponentScan annotation:

However the main application class entry point looks like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.svims.common.web.config")
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And there is another class with the `@Configuration` annotation in the `com.svims.common.web.config` package that isn't found or the beans inside this configuration just aren't loaded.

I have tried adding this to the main application class

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.svims.common.web.config", 
    includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter( Configuration.class ) })
```

To ensure the scan is configured to find these types of classes but it still doesn't work.

I can only assume that Spring MVC bootstraps in a way as to ignore these configurations but I can't find any reference to this in the documentation.

Does anyone know what is going on or any suggestions on how I might do this?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that class `Configuration` which should be located with component scanning is present on the classpath? If so, have you debugged to see whether or not that class is actually being created?

Comment: @geoand Put it as an answer and I will mark it. It is the simple of way of explaining what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check the packages being scanned again and again.